# Need to change boot order without accessing bios, Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I have following problem. I have a functioning copy of ubuntu 17.10 running but I need to change the boot order to my usb drive without accessing the bios. Is there any way to do this?

Or is there any way to install another operating system without having to change the boot order?

Comment: If the BIOS/UEFI provides a one-time boot menu, indicated during POST (initial boot, before OS), you can use that to override the BIOS/UEFI boot order for that session only. Otherwise no. Why exactly you don't want to access BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: I use a surface pro 2. The way I access the bios by holding down volume down + power. But the physical volume down button does not work with ubuntu 17.10. So I can not access it.

Comment: 1. Not BIOS, it's UEFI (not exactly a terminology quibble, but for the purpose, not really relevant). 2. Accessing the BIOS/UEFI is done *before* any OS starts to load. It doesn't have to *work with ubuntu 17.10* so it's not that. Either you aren't doing it right or there's some other problem.

Comment: And FYI, according to Microsoft it's Volume UP, not down: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023532/surface-how-do-i-use-the-bios-uefi

Comment: doing that only allows me to disable secure boot control which and disable trusted platform module. This does not allow me to boot from USB. The combination I had to use to get it done was by holding down volume down +  the power button but I see now that the issue I am dealing with right now is not as I initially suspected.

Comment: MichaelBay, [MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4036297/surface-windows-doesnt-start-on-surface) say it's volume-down except for some circumstances, I was going to suggest trying volume up. You're right wrt it not being an Ubuntu issue though, I think the questioner needs to ask how to fix the volume button? To that end I'd open it up and use a paperclip to bypass the switch - but that is dangerous to the person and equipment, definitely an "at your own risk" situation.

Comment: I just need to be able to install a different OS without entering the uefi. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @pbhj You're right. Starting with Surface 3 it has the boot options in the same menu, previous version require Vol Down+Power to change boot order.

Comment: @Slevin I already explained in the very first comment that you either change the boot order or there's nothing to do. And this are the instructions that, again, have nothing to do with the installed OS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023511 (if it doesn't boot with the USB then 2 hypotheses: USB wasn't done properly and isn't bootable in UEFI systems or the hardware itself has some other issue, either way, nothing to do with Ubuntu).

Comment: well, is it possible to boot from the grub menu? I managed to enable that and I can enter command lines.

Comment: @Slevin Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you want to install ubuntu from a live USB to your Surface Pro 2. The only way to get the USB to boot so you can install is for the UEFI to boot the USB drive. Sounds like you just hold the vol-up button and have to disable secure-boot. https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/6j9hjc/guide_installing_linux_on_surfaceseries_devices/

Comment: Try this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB for booting USB from Grub, or ask a new question. USB boot will have to be enabled already, you can't enable it without entering the "BIOS" config (well perhaps with an electron microscope you could ...).